# Java/Scala update properties file from classpath

Tags: java, file, scala, properties

I am not sure if it is possible to update a properties file loaded from classpath unless you know the absolute path?

I want to update a properties file (loaded from classapth and I do not know the absolute path of the file). I am unable to find a way to update the same properties file loaded from classapth. I wrote this code. This code loads the files doesn't update and throws exception.

```
def updateFile(encrypytedText: String, keyToBeUpdated: String) = {
    val keyLocation = PropertyFileReader.readPropertyFile("config.properties")("XXXX")
    val p = new Properties()
    //keyLocation -> another properties file from classpath
    this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResource(keyLocation).getFile
    val in = this.getClass.getClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(keyLocation)
    p.load(in)
    val allProperties = p.propertyNames()
    while (allProperties.hasMoreElements) {
      val s: String = allProperties.nextElement().toString
      p.setProperty(s, p.getProperty(s))
    }
    p.setProperty(keyToBeUpdated, encrypytedText)
    val out = new FileOutputStream(keyLocation)
    p.store(out, null)
    out.close()
}
```

Comment: Is this file iside JAR or just in classpath? Is it writeable? What kid of exception do you get?

Comment: The file is outside jar but in classpath. File is writable. I do not get any exception. I am able to read the file but when it comes to writing, it does not update the same file but creates a new in project home.

Comment: First of all if you can get `java.io.File` you can check `getAbsolutePath`. If you have it you can delete old file and create other one (it should be faster than cleaning file and writing from begin). You mentioned in description that you're getting exception and now in your latest comment you claim that there is no such one. If you're getting exception paste here which one is it and it's message. And what's that `PropertyFileReader` (library)?